# Sizable review queues with no one hitting them?

Tags: discussion, review

Just now I was idly checking my helpful flags count (a habit I got into on SO, where it's frankly far more interesting than my stats here) and noticed that I had a flag pending that was over 24 hours old. This seemed a little surprising, so I dug into the review stats and found that CV and FP have over two dozen entries in their queues, but not a soul has reviewed a single First Post today, and there's only been one Close review. How does that happen, when a single reviewer could run through their whole allotment of reviews on either queue in one go?

Comment: What's the rush? It's the weekend, no one likes moderating in the weekend...

Comment: I for one reviewed CV today. But I typically act by opening reviewed question through link to these (options within CV queue UI are too limited to my taste) - because of that, my reviews are not being "recorded"

Comment: @YannisRizos: Well, OK, but to have nobody at all with such substantial queue lengths? Seems really odd to me.

Comment: Right now the largest queue is the close votes one, with 57 questions. Not really what I'd call substantial, and I'm pretty sure reviewing activity will resume on Monday.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Hmm. Well, I'd consider a queue that one person can't get all the way through (never mind empty) to be substantial, but I expect that's a difference of terminology, and I don't want to harp on that.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for all the users with review queue access, but I can point out a few reasons why **I never use these review queues**:

- The suggested edits review queue seems to be the only one that ever actively reminds me to review it. Every time there's a little "1" next to "review" at the top of PSE, it's *always* a suggested edit review. I have no idea if this is deliberate or a bug or some function of my current rep, but it's probably the only reason why I do review suggested edits on a regular basis.
- When I first gained access to the CV/FP review queues, I tried them for about an hour, and had such a negative experience I've never looked at them since.

  - I can't evaluate the quality of an answer without first reading the question. The queues never show you both.
  - Many posts in the queues were already being edited or had comments soliciting further information from the owner, or *had already been improved*. If I had not opened the Q/A in another tab to see this information, I would have duplicated or overwritten effort that had already been made.
  - One of the questions covered by the previous bullet point turned out to be an audit question that I failed. In other words, PSE yelled at me for not taking any action on a question even though *other people had already taken action on it*. When software blindly assumes it's smarter than me I lose interest in using it very quickly
- Personally, I'm more interested in trying to clean up the terrible questions on our front page than whatever happens to be in the queues, so that's where most of my "should I VTC this?" time is spent.

Incidentally, I would love it if we got [question triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage) here. That would probably fix all of my complains about the current review queues.

Comment: wrt Triage, see [Triage and Help & Improvement review queues at sites other than Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251737/165773)

Comment: Consider filtering for a given close reason. Having another voter in the close review queue for off topic can mean that questions that *should* be migrated to stack overflow can get moved there more rapidly. It does help. Just going with the off topic filter tends to be something that would be more clear cut and actionable if those are the decisions that you want to make (every bit helps).  At 4k rep, yep - the 1 at the top is suggested edits.  At 10k it becomes 80 with all of the review queues.

Comment: @MichaelT Just tried the VC queue with an off-topic filter; you're right, that helps immensely. I might actually do more of this.

Comment: FP and LA (now?) show questions along with answers on SO and RPG.SE, and do a very good job updating comments and edits. I can't speak to CV, but I wouldn't be surprised if that's been upgraded as well. Audits have their own finicky bits, but they can be managed in my experience. So I think giving these another shot may be worthwhile.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Glad to hear that's being fixed. Sadly PSE doesn't seem to have picked up that change yet. The audit was more like a final nail in the coffin for me; I expect it to be manageable when the more fundamental problems improve. After MichaelT's filter suggestion I have a reason to look at the other review queues again, so I probably will give them another shot at some point.